# ObjectNotFound Error while using cmdlet to access AWS IAM

Tags: powershell, amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, powershell-cmdlet

I am trying to generate AWS API gateway access key through powershell. However, everytime I try to use any cmdlet it throws an error:

For example:

```
 Get-AWSCredential -ListProfileDetail
```

will result in an error like this:

> Get-AWSCredential : The term 'Get-AWSCredential' is not recognized as
>   the name of a cmdlet, function, script file, or operable program.
>   Check the spelling of the name, or if a path was included, verify that
>   the path is correct and try again. At line:1 char:1
>   + Get-AWSCredential -ListProfileDetail
>   + ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
>       + CategoryInfo          : ObjectNotFound: (Get-AWSCredential:String) [], CommandNotFoundException
>       + FullyQualifiedErrorId : CommandNotFoundException

When I display the list of commands through Get-Command the AWS cmdlets do not pop up. 
Any idea what could be the problem?

Comment: I assume you haven't installed the cmdlets. I posted the command in answers with a reference to Amazon docs.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Long story short, run this: `Install-Package -Name AWSPowerShell`

You may need to run PS as an Administrator for the `Install-Package` command to work. Additionally, you may be prompted to install 'nuget', answer yes. If you receive the security warning about PSGallery, answer yes.

Here is Amazon's docs on PS cmdlets: http://docs.aws.amazon.com/powershell/latest/userguide/pstools-getting-set-up.html

Comment: It was an access issue. Installed it.

Comment: i switched to WSL linux subsystem terminal windows terminal

Answer (score 0):

Since November 2019, AWS now provide a [modularised, lighter version](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/powershell/latest/userguide/pstools-getting-set-up-linux-mac.html) of AWS Tools for PowerShell called `AWS.Tools.*`.

**I recommend using these modules over `AWSPowerShell`**, which is the single, large-module version and will most likely include way more than you need.

You need the [`AWS.Tools.IdentityManagement`](https://www.powershellgallery.com/packages/AWS.Tools.IdentityManagement/) module for IAM-related commands e.g. `Get-AWSCredential` / `Get-IAMUser`.

Recommended setup using `AWS.Tools.Installer` (multiple benefits<sup>1</sup>):

```
Install-Module -Name AWS.Tools.Installer
Install-AWSToolsModule AWS.Tools.IdentityManagement
```

Minimal setup:

```
Install-Module -Name AWS.Tools.Common
Install-Module -Name AWS.Tools.IdentityManagement
```

---

<sup>1: as per above docs</sup>

> *The `AWS.Tools.Installer` module simplifies the installation and update of other `AWS.Tools` modules. `AWS.Tools.Installer` requires, automatically downloads and installs, an updated version of `PowerShellGet`. The `AWS.Tools.Installer` module also automatically keeps your module versions in sync. When you install or update to a newer version of one module, the cmdlets in the `AWS.Tools.Installer` automatically update all of your other `AWS.Tools` modules to the same version.*